# Bootstrap Pop Over not working after jQuery Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, jquery-post

I am currently paginating results on my page by using jQuery post. In the results I am limiting the length of "details" and if the length is over 49 say, it will display a span which, when clicked, will display a pop over with all of the details inside.

```
if (strlen($val['details']) > 49){
    $details = substr($val['details'], 0, 49);
    $more = "... <span style='cursor:pointer; position:relative; top:-3px;' data-content='{$val['details']}' class='label label-primary requestMore'>more</span>";
}
else{
    $details = $val['details'];
    $more = "";
    }
```

The jQuery is

```
$(function() {
      $('.requestMore').popover({
        trigger:'click',
        placement:'left',
        html:true
      });
```

This works fine initially, however, once I paginate, the pop over is no longer displayed. I understand its to do with DOM element bindings, but I haven't been able to tailor any solutions I've found so far to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to apply popover again after change the page.

```
      $('.requestMore').popover({
        trigger:'click',
        placement:'left',
        html:true
      });
```